# Several Template Items appearing twice when adding new item in VS 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS 2015 Community and when i want to add a new item to the project some of the templates are shown twice.

for example the "Class" Template is apperaing twice and also is several others.

Also i checked the following paths (where the templates of VS are stored)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates

to validate if their are maybe duplicates of the templates, but their is none.

Why is it happening? and how to fix this?